# Getting (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1) after hitting api in Browser with empty value

Tags: java

```
String str = request.getQueryString();
str = URLDecoder.decode(str);

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "&");
HashMap<String,String> _map = new HashMap<String, String>();
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    String temp = st.nextToken();
    String [] data = temp.split("=");
    _map.put(data[0], data[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not do `_map.put(data[0], data[1]);` without checking if the array has that many entries.

Depending on your requirements you may do
`if (data.length >= 2)`
and/or
`if (data.length == 1) _map.put(data[0], null);`

Comment: i have write a code for query string..if i provide all parameter's value then its working fine..i need to insert null value also if parameter value is empty..how can i manage this??

Answer (score 1):

add this code:

```
if (data.length >= 2){
    _map.put(data[0], data[1]);
}
```

This way you will know for sure that you have elements 0 and 1 so no Exception will be thrown

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: `data.length < 2`. Therefore, the element at index `1` doesn't exist. This would be caused by `temp` being equal to a string that doesn't contain the `'='` character.

Try adding print statements to see what you're dealing with:

```
String temp = st.nextToken();
System.out.println(temp);
String [] data = temp.split("=");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
_map.put(data[0], data[1]);
```

Comment: @inayatahmed What? You do realize that, for me, `localhost` points to the computer I'm using, right?

Comment: I guess that is the string he wants to parse

Comment: @user140547 Ah, that would make sense.